# Connecting two unix server's and push data from server to server using java program

Tags: java, unix, ssh, ftp

I have create a java program that will connect to unix server1 (with user name pwd),now i need to connect another server (with username password) and execute command to push data from server 1 to server 2 using java program.

Server1 connection is working fine and i can execute some basic commands in it.

Code below

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Properties;
import net.neoremind.sshxcute.core.ConnBean;
import net.neoremind.sshxcute.core.Result;
import net.neoremind.sshxcute.core.SSHExec;
import net.neoremind.sshxcute.exception.TaskExecFailException;
import net.neoremind.sshxcute.task.CustomTask;
import net.neoremind.sshxcute.task.impl.ExecCommand;
public class UnixConnect {

// String hostName, String logFile, String userName, String password
static String[] host_names = null;
static String[] user_names = null;
static String[] pwd_text = null;
public void execCommand() throws TaskExecFailException {
    ConnBean cb1 = new ConnBean("0.000.00.000", "***", "****");
     SSHExec ssh1 = SSHExec.getInstance(cb1);
      ssh1.connect();
    String[] cmd = {"cd /apps/a/b/c/logs","tail -1 aLoadJob.log"};
        CustomTask tasks = new ExecCommand(cmd);
         Result res1 = ssh1.exec(tasks);

        if (res1.isSuccess) {
            /*System.out.println(res1.sysout)*/;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Return code: " + res1.sysout);
            System.out.println("error message: " + res1.error_msg);
        }
    ssh1.disconnect();

}


/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws TaskExecFailException {
    UnixConnect ob = new UnixConnect();
    ob.execCommand();
}
```

}

In both Server i need to give username and password

Comment: Need to connect two server (server1 and server2 ) then push data from one server to another using java program

Comment: In both Server i need to give username and password

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit strange use case but I would do the following:

1. Implement bash script on server1 that would do all the job of transfering data to server2. Of course server1 has to be able to connecto server2
2. Use you program to invoke the bash script on server1.

Comment: use rsync in the shell script

Comment: My program can connect only server1 Am not aware how to connect server 2 can u help with some sample program am new to this